# How to evolve my pokemon in Pokemon go without the app making me go to the top of the pokemon list?

Tags: pokemon-go

I seem to remember being able to rename, favorite, evolve, transfer, etc. my pokemon in Pokemon Go without the app making me go back to the top of the list but for some reason, the latest update makes me go back to the top of the list when I do any of the above actions to my pokemon.

How do I make it not do that and make the behavior like before?  The reason this is a big deal to me is before when I used my Lucky Egg, I could alphabetize my pokemons and evolve all my Rattatas quickly.  Now, I have to scroll back down my list to Rattata after each evolution.  I used to be able to evolve 65 or so pokemons for each egg.  Now, I'll bet I can't evolve more than 50 because of the delay.

Thanks in advance for your advice and help.